# What would prevent me from getting into my BIOS settings?

Tags: boot, keyboard, motherboard, bios

I just fired up my new machine for the first time. The motherboard is an Asus ROG Rampage IV Extreme.

When I turn on the machine everything comes to life and the ROG logo appears on my screen and tells me to `press F2 or DEL to enter UEFI settings`. When I press (and spam it) nothing happens and machine goes not booting (to nowhere) like it does not see my key presses.

The same thing happens when I try to get into my Adaptec controller config. The screen says `press CTRL + A` to go into Adaptec BIOS. I sit there and hit the key combo and nothing happens and it just continues on without a flinch.

I was thinking it might be my keyboard. I have a Corsair K70 mechanical keyboard. So swapped it out for a cheap logitech USB keybaord and I still get the same result.

Any ideas? Could it be the USB ports I plugging into? The board does have 3.0 ports but I avoided plugging into those. I am using a pair of 2.0s at the top of the board.

Comment: I guess one easy way to test if your keyboard is working is to press Ctrl-Alt-Del on POST screen to see if it would restart the machine. If it does, then we know the motherboard is accepting key input.

Comment: I actually tried that, and there is a small window where it will accept CTRL-ALT-DEL. Then afterwards it won't. That is what is odd.

Comment: use the PS2 they have always been hardware supported right from the start. once you get in make sure that USB initilisation is turned on , and even legasy if needed. Until you get proper responces everytime turn off the fast boot things, and set to show post instead of logo, and set to show that stuff for time (5-10Sec). getting past post can be so fast nowdays.  the adaptech is probably the same issue, the usb keyboard not recognised and initilised back there that early. Almost all the new bioses have an ability to skip past setting up things, in this case it is the usb things (known)

Comment: I plugged in my old PS2 IBM model M. Nothing...

Comment: well i am not going to say reset the cmos , because you already know how to do that :-( There can be bios memory area conflicts with a secondary boards bios that gets loaded in, but i have never heard of them effecting things in that manner.  are you in any postition to pull the second bios (the card) ?  Did adaptek have any tools to "re-locate" the bios?  (I have done something like this only once, couldnt tell you how why or what)

Comment: However I did notice that once the machine is through the BIOS splash and through the adaptec bios. The Numlock, scroll lock and Caps lock no longer work. As in the lights don't toggle. In the past I have used this to know whether the hardware was locked up.

Comment: Just for kicks too, I did reset the CMOS just in the event that it might help.

Comment: Oh and also when I hit the power switch when it supposed to be done booting. It just kills power in less than 1 second. It does not seems to toggling ACPI soft power where you need to hold the button for 4 seconds.

Comment: Ohh well the Q starts to sound like, your continuing past post (just cant stop in the bios).  I see now that you have not provided any indication that your making it past post. and your right back to crashing before you even get started :-(   argg.

Comment: Well I did have to flash the BIOS using the ROG connect. The CPU I am using an Ivy Bridge E and the BIOS did not support the chip until I flashed it.

Comment: that makes it extra fun.  just depends if it doesnt support it visually appearing right (who cares) or if it doesnt support in that it fails.  If you really are back at the start (not even getting good post) then strip the machine to the least needed to post. 1 stick of ram, 1 cpu item, keyboard, 1 gpu item as needed to see, drives not nessisary for just getting to bios/uefi.  Even strip out case connects down to say 1 power item as needed.

Comment: Yeah that is what I will probably end up doing. Not looking forward to it though. What is lame is I don't have an old CPU that did not require the BIOS flash to test with.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I removed the 2nd GPU, Sound card and RAID card. The machine booted through and said `ROG-1 is updating XX%`. Now when the machine boots it says `No boot device found` I think the raid card was getting in the way of the post BIOS flash routine.

Answer (score 0):

So after taking the advice given to me. I was able to isolate the problem to the Adaptec RAID BIOS getting in the way of the Motherboard BIOS trying to finish the flashing procedure started by the ROG connect. I removed all of the add-in cards and the machine booted up to the `insert valid boot media` point with not problem. Upon rebooting I was able to get into the BIOS settings with no trouble at all.

Thanks for the help!